# Why do useEffect and useLayoutEffect show same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I understand it, React executes `useLayoutEffect` before printing DOM in browser, and `useEffect` executes after it. For example consider this component:

```
const App = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(document.body.scrollHeight); // shows 1024
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(document.body.scrollHeight); // shows 1024
  }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 1024 }}></div>
  )
}
```

I expected, it show `0` for `useLayoutEffect` and `1024` for `useEffect`, but both show `1024`

I thought `<div style={{ height: 1024 }}></div>` print after `useLayoutEffect` but apparently it's not correct...???

Comment: The whole point of `useLayoutEffect` is to get updated information from the DOM and react to those changes before the user can see any changes. So this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Another good read, [KCD useEffect vs useLayoutEffect](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect)

Answer (score 0):

Both `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` run after the initial render, so they will print the same output.

You might have missed the actual purpose of `useLayoutEffect` in this example, read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)